# What does position mean in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am exactly new in prestashop.
And now trying to build online store with prestashop.
And in some parts, i sometimes meet position option.
I can't understand about it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The 'position' in PrestaShop means the order of appearing of a thing in a list or in a grid.

For example, you can decide the order for the cms pages if you shows in a list, or the order of the categories in the 'blockcategory' module (the menù usually used in the left column), or the order of the slides for your slideshow.

It's a simple number that is used to give 'priority' or ordering the things.